# MongoDB Timestamp Java Driver Date

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get my date formatted in MongoDB so that it is not a string but an internal BSON date on each record so I can do TTL stuff.  I am using the Java driver and the new Date() method but the date keeps showing up as a string in the resulting records.  Any ideas?

```
        Date now = new Date();
        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("keyword", keyword).
            append("user", user).
            append("icon", picture).
            append("message", message).
            append("location", location).
            append("media", media).
            append("mediatype", mediatype).
            append("link", link).
            append("mood", mood).
            append("count", 1).
            append("geo", new BasicDBObject("lon", lon).append("lat", lat)).
            append("date", now);
        coll.insert(doc);
```

..

```
Creates record with date as a string: "date" : "Wed Nov 06 2013 18:35:25 GMT-0500 (EST)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing `TTL` there is support available out of the box from [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)
When you use `java.util.Date` it should result in the ISODate in Mongo. Refer [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#dates-times) .